# VBA модуль для Office или COM сборка на .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, com, office

Что будет быстрее работать VBA модуль или COM сборка на .NET в рамках офиса?

.NET имеет много интересных штук, которых нет в VBA и позволяют написать меньше кода чем на VBA.

Но вот просядет ли существенно производительность если использовать COM сборки?

Есть ли у COM сборок какие-нибудь ограничения? Например, смогу ли я передать ACCESS RecordSet и как-нибудь обработать его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под ком-сборкой имеется ввиду interop взаимодействие... Быстрее будет работать прямой доступ к файлам офиса (без посредника в виде офисной апликухи).
По линке будет немного больше информации на примере с Екселем:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Если коротко: нужно искать сторонние решения, а не пользоватся Интеропом т.к. уж больно криво и медленно все через него.

Если же вопрос ставить исключительно в рамках "Что будет быстрее работать VBA модуль или COM сборка на .NET в рамках офиса?",

то VBA должен работать быстрее т.к. он уже имеет доступ к данным напрямую, без посредников.

Но вообще бейсик устарел в принципе. Он просто на просто неудобный. Особенно это касается VBA. И IDE у VBA просто нереально каличная и вообще не апгрейдится и не совершенствуется уже более 15ти лет. Потому лично я бы предпочел c#.

> Например, смогу ли я передать ACCESS RecordSet и как-нибудь обработать его?

про это ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

> Что будет быстрее работать VBA модуль или COM сборка на .NET в рамках офиса?

Тут всё зависти от задачи. Если она относиться к обработке бизнес данных оторвано от интерфейса, то .NET определённо выигрывает. Если же производительность интересует в рамках реакции на пользовательские действия, то VBA здесь будет предпочтительней, так как во взаимодействии с .NET всегда нужно помнить про маршалинг данных.

> .NET имеет много интересных штук, которых нет в VBA и позволяют написать меньше кода чем на VBA.

Тут не надо обольщаться, так как в дополнении к функционалу бизнес логики вам придётся писать функционал по взаимодействию .NET с Office API. Сразу скажу, нормальных интеропов от Microsoft нет.
Основная проблема будет связана с моментами создания и удаления COM объектов, т.е. утечками памяти, так как потеря ссылки на COM объект не приводит к моментальному освобождению памяти, занятой этим COM объектом. Придётся в голове всегда держать мысль о возможности использования [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx).
Вдобавок, столкнётесь с корявыми автоматически созданными названиями функций и свойств.
Далее возник вопрос поддержания функционала для разных версий Офиса.

В какой то момент это начинает доставать и задумываешься про VBA с аргументом,что он был сделан, чтобы удобней было работать с Office API. Скорее Office API затачивался под VBA.

Как альтернатива захочется посмотреть на такие стороние проекты по взаимодействию с Офисом, как [NetOffice](https://netoffice.codeplex.com/).

> Есть ли у COM сборок какие-нибудь ограничения? Например, смогу ли я передать ACCESS RecordSet и как-нибудь обработать его?

*ACCESS* - это, наверное, Microsoft Access?

COM и .NET это детище одного и того же Microsoft-а, так что риски связанные с невозможностью взаимодействия минимальные. Так можно спокойно работать из .NET с ADO.